# How to extract string constant in the source code using LLVM api

Tags: llvm

I want to extract string constants in the source code of a program. 
For example, in the code snippet below:

```
char *s;
if(strcmp(s, "test")){ 
    do something
}
```

`"test"` is the string I want to grab.

What's the easiest way to do that with LLVM?

Comment: run a module pass and get global variables list with @.str  name pattern. Check the compiled ll file it will be more clear.